# Funcitonal component is re-rendering but not updating the UI even though the array is empty

Tags: reactjs

Version of react - **17.0.2**

I have a piece of code that checks if an image errors (`img.onerror`) out and removes the item associated with the image if it does. 
I have a state to store the ids of the items that error out and then filter out these items from the original list.
The problem is all my items are erroring out and the filtering is returning an empty array and I've verified it's empty by rendering `array.length` onto the UI. However this is not removing the items from the ui. I'm using key prop as well and the ids are unique. 
However, removing the key prop resolves this issue.
Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
const ListComponent = ({list}) => {
  const [imgErrorIds, setImgErrorIds] = useState([])

  const validList = useMemo(
    () =>
      list.filter(
        ({ id }) =>
          !imgErrorIds.find(
            (imgId) => imgId === id,
          ),
      ),
    [imgErrorIds, list],
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    list.forEach(({ imageUrl, id }) => {
      const img = new Image()
      const validImgUrl = imageUrl
      img.onerror = () => {
        img.onerror = null
        setImgErrorIds((imgErrorIds) => [
          ...imgErrorIds,
          id,
        ])
      }
      img.src = validImgUrl
    })
  }, [list])
  return (<>
      validList.map(
          ({ 
            name, 
            id, 
            imageUrl,
          }) => 
              <div key={id}>
                <img src={imageUrl}/>
                <p>{name}</p>
              </div>)
          </>)
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David I have added the code associated with this issue. Hope this will help.